# Remove mixed content warnings for development in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mixed-content

I am developing a chrome extension which loads a url in an iFrame. The actual url is hosted using https, however I want to debug it on localhost, thus wanted to allow mixed content. I can do that by allowing unsafe scripts by clicking the shield icon present in the address bar. The problem is it still generates a lot of warnings in the developer console which spams the console and doesn't let me see the actual debug messages.
Is there a way to remove the Mixed Content Warnings from the console, just for the development purpose?

The warning text example is as follows -

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://localhost:8080/test.css'. This content should also be served
>   over HTTPS.

Comment: have you tried the chrome startup parameters like nosecurity and such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use Filters to select the Logs and Errors and deselect everything else. The Filter option is available in the console view toolbar.